# How to nest listview in listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview

I am trying to nest the ListView in a Listview as per the below code, the Listview on top is scrolling horizontally and the nested ListView is scrolling vertically . for the nested ListView I am facing the error of

> Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and
> constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In
> this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of
> horizontal space in which to expand.

How should I resolve it so that the Nested View is also shown in the below code?

```
new Container(
        child: new ListView(
          
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           children: <Widget>[
            ListView(
              

              scrollDirection:Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20,10, 0),
                
                width: screenSize.width,
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Row(children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Text1'),
                        Text('Text1'),
                      ],),
                      Row(children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Text1'),
                        Text('Text1'),
                      ],),

                    ],),
                    
                    new Container(
                     //ERROR POINT
                      child: new ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            width: screenSize.width,
                             child: new Center(
                              child: new Text(
                                'RED',
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 40.0,
                                    color: Colors.white
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            width: screenSize.width,
                            child: new Center(
                              child: new Text(
                                'BLUE',
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 40.0,
                                    color: Colors.white
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            width: screenSize.width,
                            child: new Center(
                              child: new Text(
                                'ORANGE',
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 40.0,
                                    color: Colors.white
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),],
            ),
            new Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: screenSize.width,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text(
                  'BLUE',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: screenSize.width,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text(
                  'ORANGE',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO NOT wrap widgets with an empty `Container`

For nested `ListView` you have to constrain its width via either `SizedBox` or `Container`, like so:

```dart
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text('data'),
          Text('data'),
          Text('data'),
        ],
      ),
      width: 300,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text('data'),
          Text('data'),
          Text('data'),
        ],
      ),
      width: 300,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text('data'),
          Text('data'),
          Text('data'),
        ],
      ),
      width: 300,
    ),
  ],
)
```

If you want to keep all nested scroll views positions you could wrap them in a `SingleChildScrollView` with `Row`, but it seems something is not quite right in your decision

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('data $index'),
            itemCount: 200,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('data $index'),
            itemCount: 200,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('data $index'),
            itemCount: 200,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('data $index'),
            itemCount: 200,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('data $index'), itemCount: 200),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('data $index'), itemCount: 200),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: thanks Andrey for the guidance, One more issue I am facing with same thing is that, when I am scrolling the list, it is not holding that position and comes rolls back to the top of the list, how should I resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use such strange construction?